# Detect MacBook webcam usage without taking photo or recording?

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, bash, camera, webcam

I am attempting to write either a bash script or dedicated piece of software to live monitor my Macbook Pro's webcam activation in a similar manner to the green indicator light on the laptop itself.

How can I access the status of the camera as it's being used by other apps (Primarily Zoom, where the camera access might be turned on and off moment to moment) without interrupting said access?

Comment: OverSight is exactly this and open-source: https://github.com/objective-see/OverSight

Comment: Also Micro Snitch non-open-source https://obdev.at/products/microsnitch/index.html